# Finding common columns in two dataframes and retaining only those columns that are common between the two

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-cleaning

I have a dataset that has gene names. The gene names In that dataset I wanted to extract them from  two other datasets which are `gd` and `cd`.

`common_genes` is a vector that has the the gene names that I want to search

I want assistance on how, I can be able to have common columns in both the `cd` and `gd` datasets, using the common genes. This is because my analysis will require me to do comparisons between those two datasets.

```
#Extract those that are present in the `gd` dataset.
common_genes <- intersect(gene_names, colnames(gd))
# extract these 300 genes too from the `gd` for common genes
A <- gd[, common_genes]
#Extract these 300 genes too from the `cd` dataset.
common_genes2 <- intersect(gene_names, colnames(cd))
B<-cd[,common_genes]
```

The output I get is for `A` 150 genes out of 300 and `B` 200 genes out of 300.

My desired output is the example  below:

```
A
RPL26 MS4A1 ELK1 SNIP1
200   300     400     534
B
RPL26 MS4A1 ELK1 SNIP1
100    81    91  112
```

Comment: hi thole, can you be more specific about what you want. It's unclear why you wouldn't just use intersect on the column names?

Comment: @Mark thank you. So I had a dataframe that had 300 genes. So I wanted to search for those gene names in the dataframes ```gd``` and ```cd```. What I found is that out of 300 genes ```gd``` has 150 and ```cd``` has 200 out of 300. My desire to create an instance where both ```gd``` and ```cd``` will have the same genes for example where they can be both having 90 genes, which are the same. I  also want to add that the sizes of these datasets are not the same.

Comment: ah and the ones in gd are not in cd? Can you share the colnames for each? :-)

Comment: @Mark yes, so some of the column names (genes) in ```gd``` are not present in ```cd```. So the 90 is just an example, I was trying to say that now I want a situation where the genes in ```gd``` can be also present in ```cd```, and I remove all those that are not present in both datasets.

Comment: that sounds like the perfect situation for intersect?

Comment: @Mark Oooh  I see what you mean now, I will give it a try. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your example isn't reproducible, I created my own

```
df1 <- data.frame(
    a = 1:3,
    b = 2:4,
    c = 3:5)
df2 <- data.frame(
    b = 4:6,
    c = 5:7,
    d = 6:8)

# it's unclear to me why you wouldn't think to use intersect, when it's right there in your question?
common_cols <- intersect(colnames(df1), colnames(df2))

df1 <- df1[,common_cols]
df2 <- df2[,common_cols]
```

df1 afterwards:

```
  b c
1 2 3
2 3 4
3 4 5
```